# Tensorflow : ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7.8 and PyCharm.

First, I installed Python 3.7.8. Then I installed PyCharm.

I am trying to run Python code, to be specific Tensorflow code. I follow these instructions here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/site-assets/downloads/marketing/cert/Setting_Up_TF_Developer_Certificate_Exam.pdf
Page 4-8.

As in the instructions I create a new PyCharm project:

[image: exa1]

Then in the preferences for this Project, choosing Python Interpreter I install the following packages:

- tensorflow
- tensorflow-datasets
- numpy
- pillow
- urllib3

All get installed succesfully:

[image: exa2]

Then I create a new Python file:

[image: exa3]

I run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version)
```

[image: exa4]

However, I get error(s): "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

How can I fix this?

Comment: according to this thread : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749 can you try to downgrade to tensorflow 2.0 ? this thread also : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35618, some people seems to run into the same issue and you might be one of them

Comment: @yAzou No, because I need/want TF 2.2.0.

Comment: @yAzou Well, but when I downgrade I only have 2.0.0? So this is not a good solution, because I really need/want the latest version of TF.

Comment: Okay, from thoses threads (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35618#issuecomment-596631286) , It seems that you need to download that lastest microsoft redistributable C++ from here, can you try that ? : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Please let me know if it solves the problem. Also I can suggest you another way (that i personnaly use all the times for those type of package) : you can use a dockerized interpreter. You can get the latest version of the tensorflow image (from the hub) and run it as an interpreter (this avoid all DLL missing issues). Let me know if you want me to post an answer with this stuff too (of course this implies to install Docker first)

Comment: @yAzou Yes, this works, please add it as an answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot for your fast fix! I am not that advanced to fully understand what you mean with your other way, but yes, post it.

Comment: I posted the two ways

Comment: I added a more complete guide with screenshots, if you wanna try the Dockerized solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

According to this thread :
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35618#issuecomment-596631286

downloading that lastest microsoft redistributable C++ from here :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

will solve your problem

**EXTRA 1 : Use Docker as a Python Interpreter in Pycharm**

Pycharm has a usefull tool that I personally use all the time :
Docker as an interpreter.

This implies to install Docker but once you got it, you can download pretty much all the images with dependecies pre-installed and ready for work !

In your case :

1. If you dont have it Download Docker for windows (https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows/)
2. Run this command from you cmd : `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow`
3. check that you have the tensorflow image by running `docker images` command. you should get this output :

[image]

4. Open new project in pycharm
5. go to `Setting | Project | Project interpreter`
6. Click on the three vertical dots to `Add` a new interpreter
7. you should get to this window (on the left click on "Docker"):
   [image]
8. click on "OK"

And Let's code !

Now if you need another big dependecy like this one, you can always reproduce those steps with the specific dependency image from docker hub

For further details, here is the official tutorial from JetBrains :
[How to make Docker container as an interpreter in PyCharm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/#:%7E:text=Make%20PyCharm%20Docker%20Interpreter&text=We%20need%20to%20define%20a,dialog%2C%20click%20the%20Docker%20button.)

**EXTRA 2 : Use Docker as a Python Interpreter in VSCode**

For some of users that using python in VSCode (I personally don't), I've found those steps to achieve the same configuration (Docker as python interpreter) in VSCode :

1. Install the Python extension
2. Install the Remote - Containers extension
3. Open the Command Pallette and type Remote-Containers, then
   select the Attach to Running Container... and selecet the running
   docker container
4. VS Code will restart and reload
5. On the Explorer sidebar, click the open a folder button and then enter /code (this will be loaded from the remote container)
6. On the Extensions sidebar, select the Python extension and install it on the container
7. Whenprompet on which interppreter to use, select /usr/local/bin/python
8. Open the Command Pallette and type Python: Configure Tests, then
   select the unittest framework

   Source for this part : [Setting Up a Python Remote Interpreter Using Docker](https://dev.to/alvarocavalcanti/setting-up-a-python-remote-interpreter-using-docker-1i24)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to install Anaconda and set the interpreter to the Anaconda/python.exe found in the directory Anaconda is installed.