# How do I remove this error which comes after using import keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Tensorflow and Keras and stuff and I'm getting this error now when I try importing Keras.
Surprisingly, Keras was working fine until last night.
I had issues with installing OpenCV and somehow I successfully installed that library. But then I started getting errors for CUDA drivers and cuDNN.
I somehow fixed those errors too by downloading cuda_11.0.3_win10_network and cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.1. Now I am stuck with these TensorFlow errors and I do not know what to do.
Please Help.
Thanks!!

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-88d96843a926> in <module>
----> 1 import keras

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 from . import losses_utils
      8 from . import metrics_utils

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
      2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
      3 from .load_backend import floatx
      4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
      5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py in <module>
     88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     91 else:
     92     # Try and load external backend.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
      7 from tensorflow.python.framework import device as tfdev

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     30 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Do you have the required DLL's installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623184/error-failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime)

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758688/tensorflow-importerror-dll-load-failed